# Firebase subscription doesn't return values second time the page is loaded

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, observable, ionic4

I have an app that loads some tricks. In the first iteration (next, next, play) the subscription works properly. In the second iteration (end, next, next, play) it doesn't load the tricks anymore.

The Observable is correct, it is from firebase that the tricks don't provide.

Here is some code:

```
    console.log('did enter');
    this.startDate = Date.now();

    this.params = this.paramsService.get();
    console.log(this.params);
    console.log(this.trickService.getTricks());

    var myTricks = this.trickService.getTricks()
    myTricks.subscribe(tricks =>{
        console.log(tricks);
```

````
    this.tricksCollection = db.collection<Trick>('tricks');

    this.tricks = this.tricksCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
  }
  getTricks() {
    console.log(this.tricks);
    return this.tricks;

  }```

Anyone got a clue, I would appreciate,

Alex
````